# Can you explain me in a easy way what the use of Cyclic Prefix in OFDM is?

Tags: ofdm, lte

I cannot understand why cyclic prefix is used. I know that it mitigates the effect of ICI but I can't see how. Can you explain please? Formulas and mathematics is well accepted. Thanks.

I read this [Cyclic prefix vs. guard interval. Why use one over the other?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/cyclic-prefix-vs-guard-interval-why-use-one-over-the-other) but it doesn't explain me why. I still do not understand

Comment: There's actually quite a few posts that explain cyclic prefixes on this site; if you look at the "related" tab right of this question, you'll find several.

Comment: @Luigi2405, Cyclic Prefix in OFDM serves many purposes. The main purpose is to keep the orthogonality between subcarriers with a simple one-tap receiver, hence helps to mitigate ISI (and somehow ICI). Take a look at http://www.dsplog.com/2008/02/17/cylcic-prefix-in-orthogonal-frequency-division-multiplexing/